# Is it ok to use fraught in a sentence without saying what the thing is fraught with?

Tags: word-usage

Ex. is it ok to say such and such is fraught. Full stop? In a case where the context makes it clear what its fraught with?

Comment: I've never heard it used that way where I live (US Midwest).

Comment: It's an archaic word that survives in the language today mainly through the idiom *fraught with*.  It would be ok to use outside the idiom form if you were, for instance, doing a play about the 18th century and wanted to say the ship was filled with cargo.  *The ship be fraught, mateys!*.  However, using it today outside the idiom form would be like using *spake* or *thou* or *sayeth* - it's not a crime but people will probably look at you strangely.

Comment: The sense @Brillig alludes to (laden, cargoed, equipped) is the original meaning of the word and would not be used in normal speech or writing today. There is another sense of the word which is used without _with_, that of being anxious, stressed out, harassed; this only (or at least usually) applies to people. This is a different usage from something being _fraught with_ something, so even though you can use the word without _with_, the answer to your question is **no**: you cannot use _fraught_ in the sense of _fraught with X_ without the _with_ there.

Answer (score 5):

This question came up in Ben Zimmer's "[On Language](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/05/23/magazine/23FOB-onlanguage-t.html?module=Search&mabReward=relbias%3Ar%2C)" column in the May 21, 2010 *New York Times*. Zimmer does a nice job of outlining the history of the *with*-less *fraught*. In particular, he points to the 1920s as seeing the first occurrences of *fraught* "without even a hint of an object":

> The earliest example I've found so far comes from a 1925 serialized story by Henry Leyford Gates about a flapper named Joanna. In one installment Gates writes, "It was Joanna who at last broke the fraught silence." The lyrical phrase *fraught silence*, perhaps evoking *pregnant pause*, shows up again in books from 1934, 1946 and 1958. Another early use is in George O'Neil's 1931 novel about the poet John Keats, "Special Hunger": "For Keats this was a singularly *fraught* circumstance." *Circumstances*, along with anxiety-ridden *situations*, *issues* and *relationships*, would soon become familiar companions for *fraught*.

According to Zimmer, most of the increase in the usage has occurred in the past couple of decades. The entire column is well worth reading. Though Zimmer doesn't say so, I suspect that the usage may be much more firmly established in the United States than in the UK. In any event, I see it often in the *New York Times* and in the *New Yorker*.

A Google Books search turns up matches for unaided *fraught* as early as John Higgins, [*The Mirour for Magistrates*](http://books.google.com/books?id=7YY7AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA28&dq=%22fraught%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Jzr-U8SCF4f7iwKNyICACQ&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22fraught%22&f=false) (1587):

> "Or sith the Græcians will thee for to take
>
> The noble Laie Iunogen to wyfe,
>
> If thou so please, let him her dowry make
>
> Of golde, ships, siluer, corne, for our reliefe,
>
> And other thinges, which are in Græcie eyfe,
>
> That we so **fraught** may seeke some desert shore,
>
> Where thou and thyne may raygne for euermore.

Here *fraught* means simply "freighted"—that is, laden or loaded.

By the 1800s, this earlier sense of stand-alone *fraught* had almost died out, and virtually all occurrences of *fraught* occurred in tandem with *with*. One of the few exceptions appears in a review of "[The Obligations of the British Churches to Foreign Interference. A Sermon preached before the London Missionary Society, at Tottenham Court Chapel, May 12, 1825,By Richard Hamilton](http://books.google.com/books?id=s_QDAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA426&dq=%22the+fraught%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YE7-U-eJF87BiwLu7YGADA&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBjgo#v=onepage&q=%22the%20fraught%22&f=false)," in *The Congregational Magazine* (August 1825):

> When "the right hand of fellowship was given them that they should go unto the heathen ;" when "they kneeled down on the shoe and prayed ;" when the full sob of nature interrupted the utterance of affection ; when the bark, stretching before the wind, left indistinct and then imperceptible to them the weeping band which, in their turn, now lost sight of the fluttering speck ; when the loneliness of ocean comported with their desertion ; when the wind caught up their sighs, and the wave drank their tears ; when the bursting heart found no external solace, and the **fraught** bosom no reciprocation ; oh ! who can measure their sacrifices, who record their straggles, who feel their throes?

Another occurs in this speech from David Brown, *[The Prophet of St. Paul's](http://books.google.com/books?id=G6zQAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA358&dq=%22the+fraught%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YE7-U-eJF87BiwLu7YGADA&ved=0CCIQ6AEwATgo#v=onepage&q=%22the%20fraught%22&f=false)*, serialized in *The North American Magazine* (April 1835):

> *Francis.* Bid me be dumb: but let me gaze upon thee,
>
> Till the **fraught** soul shall surfeit on thy charms.

An from a London Clergyman, "[A Summer Sunday on the Righi](http://books.google.com/books?id=97YXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA20&dq=%22the+fraught+clouds%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-Fj-U9GDJ9HnoATH3oC4Bg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20fraught%20clouds%22&f=false)," in *"Wind Wafted Seed"* (1868):

> It was as if an invisible hand had arrested the **fraught** clouds till the last day of the week, in order to make the first day emerge with all the greater majesty and splendour.

The earliest twentieth-century instance of *with*-less *fraught* that a Google Books search finds is from "[Unforgotten](http://books.google.com/books?id=3O4UAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA236&dq=%22the+fraught%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=11b-U_P5D8-7ogTZ_4C4Bw&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBDgy#v=onepage&q=%22the%20fraught%22&f=false)," in *Genealogy of the Tapley Family* (1900):

> With folded hands and wistful eyes,
>
> We look and listen, and ask to know
>
> What would God have us realize
>
> As the **fraught** days come and go?

And the first prose occurrence is from Winifred James, *[Out of the Shadows](http://books.google.com/books?id=DmRDAAAAIAAJ&q=%22the+fraught+pause%22&dq=%22the+fraught+pause%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qlr-U5zbK9LcoASbjIKYBA&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBA)* (1924) [combined snippets]:

> The little one stretches out *his* hand to his brother, but she forbids it.
>
> "He is no baby," she says, " he must get himself up," and with the language of the **fraught** pause and the compelling eye, he who is no baby, but six years old quite, gets on to his feet and follows obediently.

A Google Books search for "[the fraught silence](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20fraught%20silence%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1969&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl)" (which may or may not be representative of the resurgent usage overall) returns dozens of matches; but only five are from before 1970, and most are from 1990 or later.

Comment: I've noticed a few usages in NYT recently. I'm looking at one in NYT EducationLife special/section for Sunday 12 April that reads "... speaking up about who they are and what's needed to make their path to a degree less fraught."

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, but I don't think so.

> Fraught
> -- (of a situation or course of action) filled with or destined to result in (something undesirable).

[Google Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+fraught)

This suggests that it requires two other things - a situation and a unpleasant noun. For example:

> The stunt          was fraught     with peril
>
> The situation   was fraught     with something undesirable (serious and immediate danger)

[Google Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+peril)

I speak British English, and I've never heard, or read it used on its own.

However, it can be used in this meaning (apparently):

> Marked by or causing distress; emotional: "an account of a fraught mother-daughter relationship” ( Francesca Simon).

But you still can't say:

> The stunt was fraught.

Fraught with what!? I have to know! Tell me!<sup>1</sup>

It's like saying:

> The car crashed into the. <sup>2</sup>

Into the what!? I have to know! Tell me!

<sup>1 Peril still. Or danger, but peril is cooler.</sup>

<sup>2 [It was wet concrete. (No. 3)](http://www.celebritycarsblog.com/top-10-most-idiotic-celebrity-car-accidents/)</sup>

Comment: I was thinking more: "This approach is a little fraught" to mean risky, carrying risk, in a context where it would be obvious that risk was the thing it was fraught with.

Comment: No, that doesn't work, at least I would never say that, I would add on what it was fraught with (BrE btw, and we use fraught more in that way than in AmE)

Answer (score 1):

Probably. One of the meanings of Fraught is "distressed", how ever the word is used so rarely that except for special circumstances, I might suggest using a different word.

Comment: I think it's quite common in BrE? Admittedly it's mainly restricted to negotiations, arguments and complexities, which might be what you meant by special circumstances.

Comment: I’m not sure I’d call it common exactly (not in my experience, at least), but there’s nothing wrong with “He sounded a bit fraught when I spoke to him earlier”, meaning that he sounded a bit anxious, harried, and stressed out.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes. It is used quite a lot in that way in Britain.

Answer (score 1):

Here in Canada I have recently heard it used many times by the "hip" crowd on public broadcast radio without any *with + something negative*.  I find that it just doesn't sound right when used on its own.  I find myself wanting to know what a situation is fraught with.  A radio announcer will talk about a "fraught" relationship in an author's life, etc.
It reminds me of the way academics begin to answer every question with "so".
I find these usages annoying and way too "hipster" for my taste.